# How can I recover my system after tasksel uninstalled too many packages?

Tags: package-management, tasksel

So I was using Tasksel to install the MATE desktop env to try it out as an alternative to GNOME.

After that lengthy installation of MATE, MATE itself worked, but when using GNOME again, GNOME slowly started failing. Mostly using the Desktop Links of Nautilus, which broke. Nautilus only worked when started from the terminal and leaving that open.

This started days ago and I tried reinstalling Nautilus and its depending packages several times. No avail. Uninstalled Caja as I thought it may interfere.

Today I booted into recovery mode and used `tasksel` there inside GUI mode in a Terminal, still not sure how I got into GNOME from recovery mode...

It listed MATE as U but uninstalled `ubuntu-mate-desktop` anyway.

After a while, I noticed Symbols vanish, fonts being missing, etc until all I was left was the wallpaper.

After reboot, it went straight into shell.

How do I get back into GNOME, when `tasksel` just apparently uninstalled the whole system? I can't use APT there, the network seems missing.

Tools like the `initramfs` thing are missing for some unknown reason too.

Oh, I am... Well was... Using Ubuntu 18.04 latest updates.

How can I recover my system?
Was `tasksel` always this volatile?

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to AskUbuntu!  U means Uninstall, so I'm not surprised it removed it.  Are you able to run apt-get directly, typing `/usr/bin/apt-get`?  If you can, then you can do `/usr/bin/apt-get update` and `/usr/bin/apt-get install ubuntu-mate-desktop`

Comment: There seem to be multiple questions here. Are you asking about Tasksel? Or how to reinstall Gnome? One question per Question, please.